# conda not recognized in Anaconda Prompt after deactivating environment

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, miniconda

Not sure if this is a bug, but if anyone has a suspected way to fix this issue, I would be eternally grateful.

## Description

After activating an environment in the Anaconda Prompt, when I deactivate I seem to lose all conda-related information. In other words, it returns me to a normal Windows command prompt. (No Python, no conda commands, etc.) This is rather annoying because it means I need to open another Anaconda Prompt and navigate back to the folder where I was working.

## Steps to reproduce:

1. Create a python environment with Anaconda Prompt
2. Activate it
3. Deactivate it
4. Try conda list

I just had 30 new users install Anaconda with Python 3.6 earlier this week, all on Windows, and they all experienced this issue. I have Miniconda, they have Anaconda.

## Config info

platform : win-64
conda version : 4.3.25
python version : 3.6.1.final.0

EDIT: forgot to mention that I submitted a [bug report](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/6060) just in case this was a bug. No responses at the moment.

Comment: I'm having the same issue.  At startup of the anaconda command prompt `echo %PATH%` has several paths that are not there after step 3 in your reproduction list: `..\Continuum\anaconda2`, `..\Continuum\anaconda2\mingw-w64\bin` etc.  Oddly there is still an anaconda related path that is not there in a normal command prompt: `..\Continuum\anaconda2\Library\bin` persists.

Comment: If you run `conda info --envs` there is an `env` called root, so rather than `deactivate` you can run `activate root` to switch back to the initial state of the anaconda command prompt.

Comment: Yeah, this is what I'm doing as a workaround for now. Sufficient for the moment.

Comment: one other issue I've realized, if you run `activate venv1` then want to switch to another venv and run `activate venv2` it works, but it uses the activate.bat file from the venv1 directory.  This is significant for me because I am using the activate.bat file to set environmental variables.  My current workaround is to call `activate venv2` a second time from within venv2 or go through root on the way to venv2.

Comment: Update: see my answer below, but tl;dr is that `deactivate` is supposed to act like this.

Comment: That sounds really annoying. I wonder if they have a reason for using the old `activate.bat`? I can't think of a reason why they would want to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, my understanding of `deactivate` was wrong -- it's purpose is to completely deactivate conda and remove all traces from the terminal. So this behavior is what `deactivate` is actually meant to do, not switch you to your root environment.

See the issue response here: [link](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/6060#event-1286054121).

Comment: I saw that comment from mingwandroid on the git hub bug report.  I guess the work flow is to open a new terminal every time you want to work on a new Env.  I haven't figured out how to set environmental variables similarly to a postactivate hook in virtualenvwrapper, I'm just not very good at reading `.bat` files.

Answer (score 0):

Run in Windows prompt:

```
cmd "/K" C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3
```

You will have anaconda prompt back.